# Estimating the Number of Heads from a Biased Coin

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a biased coin where:

- If the previous flip was heads, the probability of getting a heads in the next turn is 0.7
- If the previous flip was tails, the probability of getting a tails in the next turn is 0.7

**My Question:** If you flip this biased coin 100 times, on average, how many heads will you observe?

I wrote a computer simulation for this biased coin in R:

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 100  # number of coin tosses
m <- 10000  # number of repetitions
coin <- c(0, 1)  # 0 = heads, 1 = tails
prob <- c(0.5, 0.5)  # initial probabilities
percent_heads <- numeric(m)

# Repeat the process m times
for (j in 1:m) {
    results <- numeric(n)
    # Simulate coin tosses
    for (i in 1:n) {
        toss <- sample(coin, 1, prob = prob)
        results[i] <- toss
        if (toss == 0) {  # if heads
            prob <- c(0.7, 0.3)
        } else {  # if tails
            prob <- c(0.3, 0.7)
        }
    }
    percent_heads[j] <- sum(results == 0) / n  # calculate percent of heads
}


df <- data.frame(Experiment = 1:m, PercentHeads = percent_heads)
ggplot(df, aes(x = PercentHeads)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
    labs(title = "Distribution for the Percentage of Heads", x = "Percent Heads", y = "Frequency") +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]
Based on this simulation (assuming I have done everything correctly), it seems that there is still is a roughly 0.5 probability that all flips will be heads - even though the coin does not have a 0.5 probability of getting heads AND the coin now depends on the previous result.

**I would have thought that due to this conditionally dependent coin, the coin is a lot more likely to get "stuck" in these repeated patterns of consecutive heads and consecutive tails, thus pushing the probability of getting heads away from 0.5.**

When I repeat this simulation for a fair coin where there is conditional independence - the results look almost identical to the simulation for the biased coin:

```
n <- 100  # number of coin tosses
m <- 10000  # number of repetitions
coin <- c(0, 1)  # 0 = heads, 1 = tails
prob <- c(0.5, 0.5)  # initial probabilities
percent_heads <- numeric(m)

# Repeat the process m times
for (j in 1:m) {
    results <- numeric(n)
    # Simulate coin tosses
    for (i in 1:n) {
        toss <- sample(coin, 1, prob = prob)
        results[i] <- toss
        if (toss == 0) {  # if heads
            prob <- c(0.5, 0.5)
        } else {  # if tails
            prob <- c(0.5, 0.5)
        }
    }
    percent_heads[j] <- sum(results == 0) / n  # calculate percent of heads
}
```

[image]

Can someone please help me understand why both simulations look very similar to each other even though they are fundamentally different from one another?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the probability of heads? What's the probability of tails? I'm at a loss here ... unable to calculate the *initial probability* of these events. The OP only states the *conditional probabilities*. Do you mean the coin's bias begins *only after* the first flip for which odds of heads = odds of tails?

Comment: Initial probabilities are 0.5 and 0.5

Comment: It doesn't make sense, I would say, *philosophically*. The *initial probabilities* $P(H) = P(T) = 0.5$. How does the coin *acquire* bias after the first flip? This *might* explain the, your, *quare* question. As you can see the first flip is fair and notice the *symmetry* in $P(H_2|H_1) = P(T_2|T_1) = 0.7$ The *bias* kinda *cancels* each other. We would call this, in *statistics*, a (contrived) *random error* or a carefully crafted *systematic error* that *auto  destructs*. A *suicidal bias*.

Comment: Did you have a *wider point* to state? Gracias for the question.

Comment: To further clarify, what we have here is $0.5 \pm x$. The average = $0.5$. The deviations away from $0.5$ is *equal **and** opposite*, *rocketish*. Haha 

Comment: @Agent Smith: thank you so much for your replies! I posted my own answer to this question below ... can you please take a look? Thank you!

Comment: @Agent Smith: any thoughts about this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828491/expected-value-for-sum-of-unfair-dice-equals-expected-value-for-sum-of-fair-dice

Comment: Consider a fair 2-sided coin. $P(1, 1) = P(1, 2) = P(2, 1) = P(2, 2) = 0.25$  $E(X) = 3$. Now a biased 2-sided coin with $P(1, 2) = 0.5$ The remaining probability ($0.5$) is evenly distributed among the rest of the events. $P(1, 1) = P(2, 1) = P(2, 2) = \frac{1}{6}$. The $E(X) = 3$ in this case too. *Quomodo*? Notice ... how $P(1, 2)$ has *increased* and $P(2, 1)$ has *decreased*, in combination, they *cancel* each other.

Comment: $P(1, 2) = \frac{3}{6} = 0.5$, $P(2, 1) = \frac{1}{6}$ for the biased die. As is obvious $P(1, 2) > P(2, 1)$ ... some sorta offset mechanism. I'm however unable to see a *perfect cancellation*. With stuff like $x + y = k$, and $xy = k$ where $k$ is a constant, the cancellation is clearly visible. This is more of $ax + y = k$, in concrete terms, $2 \times 0.25 + (x + y + z) = 1$. The distribution of $0.5$ among $(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)$ is apparent, resulting in $P(2, 1) = \frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 3):

The average number of heads remains 50% simply because of symmetry: the likelihood of a particular sequence of heads or tails is exactly the same as the opposite sequence where heads and tails are swapped.

More interesting, however, is why the distribution of number of heads still looks similar in shape. That can be explained by reformulating the problem slightly.

After having tossed the coin, in the next round you either let it be without tossing it with probability 0.4, or with probability 0.6 you toss it as an even coin with 50-50 chance of heads or tails.

Using the above scheme, in 60% of the cases the coin is tossed (fairly), while in the remaining 40% of cases the previous result is repeated.

So the original coin toss is similar to a fair coin being tossed but each toss counted multiple times.

Comment: @Elinar: thank you so much for your answer! I posted an answer to my own question below - can you please take a look if you have time? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The distributions *look* the same but they are most certainly not the same.  Calculate, for instance, the sample variance of the number of heads observed.  My simulation gives a value of approximately $58.5$, whereas if the flips were independent and the coin fair, the random number of heads is binomial with $n = 100$ and $p = 0.5$, hence has variance $np(1-p) = 25$.  So the dispersion of the dependent case is larger, as one would expect.

Here are the histograms, overlaid, in my computation of $10^6$ simulations per case.  The orange curve is the dependent case, and the blue is the independent (binomial) case.

[image]

The reason why it's still bell-shaped and not heavily skewed toward the extremes in the dependent case is because there's still a $0.3$ probability of not flipping the same result as the previous flip.  If you changed it to be much more strongly dependent, say the probability of the next flip being the same as the previous is $0.999$, then the shape of the distribution will be drastically different.  Try it out for yourself.

As an exercise, what *is* the family of steady state distributions described by the Markov process with transition matrix $$\mathcal P = \begin{bmatrix} \theta & 1 - \theta \\ 1 - \theta & \theta \end{bmatrix}$$ for some parameter $\theta \in (0,1)$ and the initial state vector $[0.5 \; 0.5]$?

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! i think I also thought of an explanation to this problem using stationary distributions of discrete markov chains .... I will post my reasoning as well!

Comment: I just posted my thoughts below!

Comment: if you have time, can you please tell me if my analysis is correct here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828491/expected-value-for-sum-of-unfair-dice-equals-expected-value-for-sum-of-fair-dice

Answer (score 2):

OP here, I think I thought of answer to my problem using the concept of Stationary Distributions?

As I understand, a Stationary Distribution of a Markov Chain means that : for a given transition matrix, regardless of your initial distributions  $(p^0_1, p^0_2)$, as the number of iterations goes to infinity, the probability of being in any state will converge to a fixed vector $ \pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2]$

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix} p^0_1 \\ p^0_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix}^n$$

**Part 1:** Assume a transition matrix: $P = \begin{bmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{bmatrix}$

Then, the following equation holds where $ \pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2]$ is the vector for the stationary distribution:

$$\pi P = \pi$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \pi_1 p_{11} + \pi_2 p_{21} = \pi_1$$
$$\pi_1 p_{12} + \pi_2 p_{22} = \pi_2$$

This formula allows us us to directly find out the Stationary Distribution for a given Markov Chain.

**Part 2:** As we can see, there are now 2 equations:

1. $$\pi_1 = p_{11}\pi_1 + p_{21}\pi_2$$
2. $$\pi_2 = p_{12}\pi_1 + p_{22}\pi_2$$

We know $\pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1$  because they are probabilities.

First equation for $\pi_2$:

$$\pi_2 = \frac{\pi_1 - p_{11}\pi_1}{p_{21}}$$

Substitute this into $\pi_1$ + $\pi_2$ = 1$:

$$\pi_1 + \frac{\pi_1 - p_{11}\pi_1}{p_{21}} = 1$$
$$\pi_1 (1 + \frac{1 - p_{11}}{p_{21}}) = 1$$
$$\pi_1 = \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$

Now, substitute $\pi_1$ into the equation for $\pi_2$:

$$\pi_2 = 1 - \pi_1$$
$$\pi_2 = 1 - \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$
$$\pi_2 = \frac{1 - p_{11}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$

Thus, the stationary distribution $\pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2]$ in terms of the transition probabilities is:

$$\pi_1 = \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$
$$\pi_2 = \frac{1 - p_{11}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$

**Conclusion:** Using my original example of (0.7, 0.3) and (0.7, 0.3), we can see that this approaches (0.5,0.5). This means that if we keep flipping the biased coin, in the long run, we can (paradoxically) expect the same number of heads as tails.

Interestingly enough, no matter what the transition probabilities are - as long as they "symmetric", it looks like the stationary distribution will always become (0.5,0.5)?

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: I see the word "symmetric", so I would have to say your analysis is correct. I don't follow the math though; above my paygrade, if you know what I mean.

Comment: This analysis is correct. I'm sure there must also be asymptotic expressions for the variance published which capture the dependence between subsequent tosses.

Comment: @ Einar: thank you so much for your reply! Currently I am working on this question and am also discovering counterintuitive results! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828491/expected-value-for-sum-of-unfair-dice-equals-expected-value-for-sum-of-fair-dice