# Unfair Coin Flips can still result in Equal Distributions of Heads and Tails?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a biased coin (heads = 1, tails = 2) such that :

- The probability of getting heads the first flip is 0.5
- After the first flip, the result of the next flip depends on the current flip.
- And $p_{11} =  p_{22}$ and $p_{12} =  p_{21}$
- $p_{11}$  is the probability of going from heads to heads , $p_{12}$ is the probability of going heads to tails, etc.

**My Question :** Based on a computer simulation I did earlier ([Estimating the Number of Heads from a Biased Coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827932/estimating-the-number-of-heads-from-a-biased-coin)), I think it's possible that **in this case : If we flip this coin many times, I think the number of heads will roughly equal to the number of tails**

Here is my way to approach this problem - I think it can be analyzed using the concept of Stationary Distributions

As I understand, a Stationary Distribution of a Markov Chain means that : for a given transition matrix, regardless of your initial distributions  $(p^0_1, p^0_2)$, as the number of iterations goes to infinity, the probability of being in any state will converge to a fixed vector $ \pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2]$

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix} p^0_1 \\ p^0_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix}^n$$

**Part 1:** Assume a transition matrix: $P = \begin{bmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{bmatrix}$

Then, the following equation holds where $ \pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2]$ is the vector for the stationary distribution:

$$\pi P = \pi$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \pi_1 p_{11} + \pi_2 p_{21} = \pi_1$$
$$\pi_1 p_{12} + \pi_2 p_{22} = \pi_2$$

This formula allows us us to directly find out the Stationary Distribution for a given Markov Chain.

**Part 2:** As we can see, there are now 2 equations:

1. $$\pi_1 = p_{11}\pi_1 + p_{21}\pi_2$$
2. $$\pi_2 = p_{12}\pi_1 + p_{22}\pi_2$$

We know $\pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1$  because they are probabilities.

First equation for $\pi_2$:

$$\pi_2 = \frac{\pi_1 - p_{11}\pi_1}{p_{21}}$$

Substitute this into $\pi_1$ + $\pi_2$ = 1$:

$$\pi_1 + \frac{\pi_1 - p_{11}\pi_1}{p_{21}} = 1$$
$$\pi_1 (1 + \frac{1 - p_{11}}{p_{21}}) = 1$$
$$\pi_1 = \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$

Now, substitute $\pi_1$ into the equation for $\pi_2$:

$$\pi_2 = 1 - \pi_1$$
$$\pi_2 = 1 - \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$
$$\pi_2 = \frac{1 - p_{11}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$

Thus, the stationary distribution $\pi = [\pi_1, \pi_2]$ in terms of the transition probabilities is:

$$\pi_1 = \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$
$$\pi_2 = \frac{1 - p_{11}}{p_{21} + 1 - p_{11}}$$

**Conclusion:** Thus, for all $p_{11} =  p_{22}$ and $p_{12} =  p_{21}$, we can see that ($\pi_1$, $\pi_2$) approaches (0.5,0.5). This means that if we keep flipping this type of biased coin, in the long run, we can (paradoxically) expect the same number of heads as tails.

**Is my analysis correct?**

Thanks!

Comment: At an extreme, an unfair coin that never repeats the previous throw (heads->tails->heads->tails etc) will get as close as possible to 50% for each side.

Comment: @ gnasher729: thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: Do you have any opinions about this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828491/expected-value-for-sum-of-unfair-dice-equals-expected-value-for-sum-of-fair-dice