# Expected Value for Sum of Unfair Dice equals Expected Value for Sum of Fair Dice?

Tags: probability

- Suppose there are two dice : $D_1$ and $D_2$. Both $D_1$ and $D_2$ have 6 sides (i.e. $i = 1,2,3,4,5,6$).
- If $D_1 = i$, there is a $0.5$ probability that $D_2 = i$ and an evenly distributed probability that $D_2$ equals all other remaining numbers.
- Suppose both dice are rolled $n$ times: $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, ... $(x_n,y_n)$
- The objective is to estimate the Expected Value of the sum of both dice, i.e. $Z = D_1 + D_2$ , thus we are interested in $E(Z)$

**My Problem:** Suppose there are 4 people that are trying to estimate $E(Z)$ based on these $n$ rolls

- Person 1 is provided the individual dice rolls  $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, ... $(x_n,y_n)$ and is told that the dice rolls are independent
- Person 2 is provided only with the sums of the dice rolls $z_1, z_2, ... z_n$ and is told that the dice rolls are independent
- Person 3 is provided the individual dice rolls  $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, ... $(x_n,y_n)$ and told that all outcomes of Dice 2 depends on the outcome of Dice 1
- Person 4 is provided the individual dice rolls  $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, ... $(x_n,y_n)$ and told that the outcome of Dice 2 depends on the outcome of Dice 1, but is told the exact dependence (i.e. The outcome of Dice 2 is more likely to equal to the outcome of Dice 1)

**My Question: Based on these** $n$ **rolls, which of these people will have the closest estimate to the true value of** $E(Z)$?

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Person 1: To calculate the expected value of the dice sum for Person 1, we can use the formula $E(x+y) = E(x) + E(y)$ :

$$\hat{E_{}}(Z) = \hat{E}(D_1) + \hat{E}(D_2) =  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{6} i \cdot \frac{n_{1i}}{n} \right) + \left( \sum_{i=1}^{6} i \cdot \frac{n_{2i}}{n} \right)$$

- Person 2: To calculate the expected value of the dice sum for Person 2, we can directly calculate the expected value of $z$:
  $$\hat{E}(Z) = \sum_{k=2}^{12} z \cdot \frac{n_z}{n}$$
- Person 3: To calculate the expected value of the dice for Person 3, we assume that every outcome of Dice 2 potentially depends on the outcome of Dice 1, thus resulting in a large sum of conditional probabilities (in reality, many of these will likely be $0$):

$$\hat{E}(Z) = \sum_{i=1}^{6} \sum_{j=1}^{6} (i+j) \cdot P(Y=j|X=i) \cdot P(X=i) =  \sum_{i=1}^{6} \sum_{j=1}^{6} (i+j) \cdot \frac{n_{2ij}}{n_{1i}} \cdot \frac{n_{1i}}{n}$$

- Person 4: To calculate the expected value of the dice for Person 3, we assume that the outcome of Dice 1 influences the outcome of Dice 2 as defined above:

$$E(Z) = \sum_{i=1}^{6} \left( i + \sum_{j=1}^{6} j \cdot P(Y=j|X=i) \right) \cdot P(X=i)$$

$$\hat{E}(Z) = \sum_{i=1}^{6} \left( i + \sum_{j=1}^{6} j \cdot \frac{n_{2ij}}{n_{1i}} \right) \cdot \frac{n_{1i}}{n}$$

Using the Law of Linear Expectations ([Proof of linearity for expectation given random variables are dependent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810365/proof-of-linearity-for-expectation-given-random-variables-are-dependent)), I think that as $n$ becomes larger, the estimate from all 4 people should in theory be equal to each other. But I am not sure if I have done this correctly.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: The $4$ are the same even for small $n$

Comment: @kroki: thank you so much for your reply!